# OpenShift: Is it possible to use the same secret token in two different service account?

Tags: openshift

I'm trying to set two different service account to use the same token so that when I do:

> oc get pods -n $PROJECT --server=$URL --token=$TOKEN

I will have access to two different namespace with the same token...
Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible to have two different service accounts identified by the same token. The token has an annotation, `kubernetes.io/service-account.name`, to identify the service account to which it belongs, e.g. the following token maps to `serviceaccount1`:

```
$ oc describe secret serviceaccount1-token-mwhh7 -n project1
Name:   serviceaccount1-token-mwhh7
Namespace:  project1
Labels:   <none>
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/service-account.name=serviceaccount1
    kubernetes.io/service-account.uid=23f96072-342e-11e8-9218-fec13b217f77

Type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
```

The token can only have one such annotation, so it can only be mapped to a single service account. That makes sense since otherwise OpenShift wouldn't know which service account to use when presented with that token.

That said, you should be able to give a service account in one namespace permissions to view / edit another project.

For example, if we create 2 projects:

```
oc new-project project1
oc new-project project2
```

And a service account in each:

```
oc create sa serviceaccount1 -n project1
oc create sa serviceaccount2 -n project2
```

Then grant `serviceaccount2` in `project2` permission to view `project1`:

```
oc policy add-role-to-user view system:serviceaccount:project2:serviceaccount2 -n project1
```

We can then get the token for `serviceaccount2`:

```
oc serviceaccounts get-token serviceaccount2
```

And use it to access `project1`:

```
$ oc get pods -n project1 --token=<serviceaccount2-token>
NAME                READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
django-ex-1-build   1/1       Running   0          9m
```